# how to deal with mail per hour limit in phpmailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am using PHP mailer, which is working fine, apart from i think the host is limited to 100 per hour.
below is the debug message issued after 100 have been sent.

> SERVER -> CLIENT: 550 enquiries@******.me exceeded rate limit ( 100.2 / 1h ) 2014-04-30 19:01:30  SMTP ERROR: DATA command failed: 550 enquiries@******.me exceeded rate limit ( 100.2 / 1h ) SMTP Error: data not accepted. SMTP Error: data not accepted.

i need to send out approx 1600 emails (around once every 2 weeks), but can not find out how to do this with the limit in place.

Any advice on how to do this, without the need to go back and run the script manually every hour until all emails are sent.

Hope this is the right place to post this question, only i have googled and can not find any simple answers (other than contact the host....)

In case there is a script way out of this, below is the code i am using

```
if($result = $user_obj->getAllNewsletterWhereActive($db)){
        try {
            // initiate object for mail and set smtp
            $mail = new PHPMailer(true); // the true param means it will throw exceptions on errors, which we need to catch
            $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP           
            $mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;// keep the SMTP open (remember to close at end of script)


            $mail->Host       = "mail.******.me"; // SMTP server
            $mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
            $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
            $mail->Host       = "mail.******.me"; // sets the SMTP server
            $mail->Port       = 587;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
            $mail->Username   = "enquiries@*******.me"; // SMTP account username
            $mail->Password   = "*******";        // SMTP account password
            $mail->AddReplyTo('enquiries@******.me');
            $mail->SetFrom('enquiries@******.me');
            $mail->AddReplyTo('enquiries@******.me');
            $mail->Subject = $Subject;
            $mail->isHTML(true);  



            foreach($result as $row) {
                // build simple unsubscribe link
                $resetCode = base64_encode($row->NewsletterEmail);
                $websiteLink = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/unsubscribe.php?code='.$resetCode;

                $mail->Timeout    =   60; // set the timeout (seconds)
                $mail->Body = $Message.'<br><br>Please click the below link to unsubscribe <br><a href="'.$websiteLink.'">Unsubscribe</a>'; // 
                $mail->AddAddress($row->NewsletterEmail);

                // send email and output success or fail massage
                if($mail->Send()){
                    $message .= 'Message Sent OK to '.$row->NewsletterEmail.'<br>';
                }
                else {
                    $error .= 'Message FAILED to '.$row->NewsletterEmail.'<br>';
                }

                // clear the address for the next loop
                $mail->clearAddresses();                
            }

            // close SMTP conncetion
            $mail->SmtpClose();

        } 
        catch (phpmailerException $e) {         
            echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer         
        } 
        catch (Exception $e) {          
            echo $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!          
        }

    }
    else {
        $error .= '<strong>Error! </strong>There was no email addresses returned or selected. please try again or contact support!<br>';
    }
```

Any advice greatly appreciated!

Comment: well, you need to disable the limit...

Comment: Put in a `sleep(60)` between each one, to set your limit to 60 items per hour? (That's a 60 second delay between each, i.e. one minute). You could decrease that slightly to move up to your 100/hour rate though. (Of course, don't do this in a web request - do it as a console/cron process on the server).

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I have a similar one with gmail

Answer (score 2):

**It's like this:**

1. Persist the email delivery queue to a database.
2. Use a cronjob and send 100 emails every hour *(or 99 to be safe)*.

That's it! :)

**PS**: *It's unlikely the host will lift the limit. You can also look into Amazon SES, SendGrid, SMTP.com and such services.*

Comment: Thanks, this is the answer then, looks like i need to do more work :-(

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help you but it solved the same problem for me a few months ago
http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=tlqmbNtW_x8